Bad gRPC response when using AddGrpcClient extension
I'm getting this exception if my grpc client is created via the AddGrpcClient extension:
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<MyClient>(options => options.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:50051"));


Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad
gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")'

However, if my client is created "manually" like this:
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:50051")
MyClient client = new(channel);

Then I'm able to make the request successfully. What am I missing here?

which versions of .net and grpc nuget packages are you using ?

.NET 8, Grpc.AspNetCore / Grpc.Net.Client: 2.66.0

AddGrpcClient uses the gRPC client factory, which relies on the default HTTP/2 configuration provided by .NET's HttpClient.
MyClient client = new(channel); explicitly creates a GrpcChannel with its own configuration, which might bypass certain limitations.
You could make sure the gRPC server support http2 by adding
        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ListenLocalhost(50051, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
            });
        });

And try use tls1.2 when configure httpclienthandler
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<MyClient>(options =>
{
    options.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:50051");
})
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
        };
    }
    );


Still getting the same RpcException.
